# Help Visualizing the Quotient Space

Tags: general-topology

I am reading quotient spaces for the first time and have not fully grasped the gluing process visualization to predict what quotient spaces look like. For example, if I have $$X=\mathbb{R} \times \{-1\} \cup \mathbb{R} \times \{1\}$$ with subspace topology from $\mathbb{R}^2$ and an equivalence relation defined as $$(x,y)R(w,z) \text{ if } x=w \text{ and } x,w \ne 0.$$
I would like to know how to be able to visualize the quotient space $X^*$. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quotient spaces are not always very easy to visualize. What's worse, there is no uniform method that applies to let you visualize them all. Like most things (in and out of mathematics), you simply have to experience a lot of quotient spaces to learn how to understand, and sometimes visualize, them.

For this quotient space $X^*$, first let's look at some important subspaces. First let's ignore the two points $(0,-1)$ and $(0,+1)$. Notice that $(\mathbb R - \{0\}) \times \{-1\}$ and $(\mathbb R - \{0\}) \times \{1\}$, which one can think of as "two copies of the line minus the origin", are being identified into one single "line minus the origin", a subspace of $X^*$ that I'll denote $L$.

Next, $X^* - L$ has just two other points, which I'll denote $0^- = \{(0,-1)\}$ and $0^+ = \{(0,+1)\}$. The union $L \cup \{0^-\}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$, and the union $L \cup \{0^+\}$ is also homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$.

So, one can think of $X^*$ as a [line with two origins](https://www.mathcounterexamples.net/the-line-with-two-origins/), which is what people actually call this beast. If you want to try to visualize it, imagine that you are simply looking at the actual real line, except that when you try to focus on the origin you have double vision. That's about the best one can say for this example.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer as well as the useful link. This was very helpful.